# How to use streamlit for real time data analytics?

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to stream real time financial data from an api. I want to continuously stream real-time time series data from an API or data source and see the dashboard or lineplot in streamlit. This code works and returns the df with the data, but it doesn't work in streamlit. The df in streamlit is empty. How do I add the streamed data to streamlit?

This is my code:

```
import websocket
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
import time

API = "FinhubAPI"

columns = ["symbol", "timestamp", "price", "volume"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)


def on_message(ws, message):
    global df

    data = json.loads(message)

    if "data" in data and "type" in data and data["type"] == "trade":
        trades = data["data"]

        for trade in trades:
            symbol = trade["s"]
            timestamp = trade["t"]
            price = trade["p"]
            volume = trade["v"]
            df = pd.concat(
                [
                    df,
                    pd.DataFrame(
                        columns=columns,
                        data=[dict(zip(columns, [symbol, timestamp, price, volume]))],
                    ),
                ],
                axis=0,
                ignore_index=True,
            )
            

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    ws.send('{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"AAPL"}')
    ws.send('{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"AMZN"}')
    ws.send('{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"BINANCE:BTCUSDT"}')
    ws.send('{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"IC MARKETS:1"}')


placeholder = st.empty()

with placeholder.container():
    if not df.empty:
        (fig_col1,) = st.columns(1)
        with fig_col1:
            st.markdown("### First Chart")
            fig = px.line(data_frame=df, y="price", x="timestamp")
            st.write(fig)

        st.markdown("### Detailed Data View")
        # st.dataframe(df)
        time.sleep(1)

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
    f"wss://ws.finnhub.io?token={API}",
    on_message=on_message,
    on_error=on_error,
    on_close=on_close,
)
ws.on_open = on_open
ws.run_forever()
```